# .SVG Basemap from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg, basemap

I'm having trouble getting a gray basemap of Philadelphia in a vector scalable format using qgis. I've tried using the openstreets basemap plugin, and then taking that to print composer, but that doesn't seem to work as it aught to. I've also uploaded shapefiles of rivers, roads, and railways to try to make my own basemap, which looks nice, but doesn't really work when exported to svg either.

Are there collections of svg basemaps available?

Is there a better way to solve this problem than the ways I attempted?

Comment: What didn't work when you try to make your own base map  ?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work as it ought to" is too vague for us to help. What actually happens when you put the open street map in the print composer? How does it differ from what you want to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/241383/81764

Comment: The Openstreetmap basemap is built of raster tiles, so not the right datasource for a SVG output. You have to look for vector data sources.

Comment: You all are awesome, @csk that reference is very helpful. And you're right "doesn't seem to work as it aught to" was vague: the person I was sending this too didn't give me too many reasons as to what was wrong. From what I can tell one issue was that there were raster images embedded in the svg.

Comment: @AndreJ You're also totally correct. I've gone and rebuilt the map from just vector data sources (shapefiles) and that produced a better result. By opening the file in inkscape and following the instructions of the thread csk left, I'll likely be able to get to a great product. Thanks all!